# Can anyone identify this wheel-like part from the Kazi 10005 80cm WW2 German Railway Gun "Dora"?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands

Pictures below show a part from the [Kazi 10005 80cm WW2 German Railway Gun "Dora"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G64tpJfPrqs).

I've been looking on Bricklink for this part, but I can't seem to find it.

Does anyone know if this actually exists in LEGO? And if so, what's the part number?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it the same part or two parts? Bottom one looks similar to https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=91049

Comment: @Alex : I think you're right. This does seem to he piece 91049. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: not sure if I should post this as an answer?

Comment: @Alex : Why not? I'll definitely upvote your answer & will mark it as an accepted answer if I have confirmation that your assessment is accurate. Also, your answer might help other people who have a deformed version of this piece, or where it is missing...

Answer (score 2):

I know of similarly looking LEGO piece - [Minifigure, Utensil Barbell Weight](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=91049).

[image][image]

Comment: The part has been ordered. I'll be able to verify whether this is the correct piece once it's arrived.

Comment: The LEGO barbell appears to be single-sided (with a stud fitting on the top side only)

Answer (score 1):

Kazi bricks are not manufactured by Lego. They're a separate brand of "compatible" bricks manufactured in China and, as such, won't appear on Bricklink since that site is reserved exclusively for the sale of official LEGO blocks.

> *"The Site acts as an online platform for sellers to sell LEGO® items and designs for a model or creation using bricks"*

You can find the full Kazi set available online [here](https://www.yourwobb.com/collections/kazi-military-series/products/kazi-ky10005-1-72-german-80cm-he-railway-gun-dora). I haven't seen any sites that sell Kazi bricks individually, but AliExpress host their '*[official online store](https://kazi.aliexpress.com/store/2295044)*'. I'm reasonably certain if you contact Ali with an enquiry about replacing a specific (missing?) brick, they can pass it along to Kazi and get it sent out to you, especially if you stress that you're a loyal customer of their brand.

Comment: Maybe OP is looking to build model produced by Kazi but with LEGO bricks?

Comment: @Alex - From what I can tell, there's not necessarily a direct analogue between Kazi blocks and LEGO bricks. They fit each other, but they're not a 1-1 copy. Kazi has many bricks that are entirely unique

Comment: it is not uncommon for clone-brands to develop unique pieces. Do you happen to know what would be the closest analog for Kazi item in form of LEGO?

Comment: @Alex - I wouldn't even know where to begin. It's certainly not a common piece. I suspect it to be a unique, but it could easily just be a piece cloned from an obscure LEGO set.

Comment: The issue I had, was a deformed piece that needed replacement. I did contact my supplier in China, and they suggested I bought the equivalent LEGO piece from a local Bricklink store and they'd repay it, as that would be cheaper & more efficient than just sending the individual Kazi piece from China. @Alex identified this piece as 91049 in a comment, and I believe he's correct. Either way, I'm not familiar with any Kazi parts that have no LEGO equivalent. Maybe you're confusing Kazi with Quan Guan? If not, what parts are you thinking of?

Comment: @JohnSlegers - His piece seems visually to be dissimilar to the one in your picture but if you're happy that it's close enough, then who am I to argue?

Comment: @Valorum : The part has been ordered. I'll be able to verify whether this is the correct piece once it's arrived.